# flask resfull app permission error on file save

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm trying to upload a file to my REST API, and then save it in a directory.
It's running on the build in flask development server.

I get this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'uploads/'
```

Here is my code:

```
class Upload(Resource):
    def post(self):
        new_file = request.files['file']
        new_file.save('uploads/', 'file_name')
```

I understand why I get this error, but I can't figure out how to change permissions. How is that done?

I'm on windows 7.

BR Kresten

Answer (score 2):

Did you set `app['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads'`?

Here is what I thought better for your uploaded files:

```
home_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(home_dir, "upload")
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

class Upload(Resource):
    def post(self):
        new_file = request.files['file']
        file_name = secure_filename(new_file.filename)
        new_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name))
```